# Syntax Highlighting Bug

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

For some reason the syntax highlighter is displaying `results_t` the color used for type names in the Python code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737504/355230). In Python the convention is to capitalize the first letter of such names, although there are many exceptions to that in its standard library.

I suspect it has to do with the `_t` suffix which may be a naming convention for type-names in some other language(s).

Comment: Bugs in the syntax highlighter need to be reported to the Google Prettify project, see the FAQ I duped you too.

Comment: In this case it is the `_t` suffix, yes, see https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/3be983976039d0b17963cf9f40e5c6fa18e68933/src/prettify.js#L949

Comment: @Martijn: Impressive detective work...but it looks difficult to fix without adding some kind of "except for these languages" capability (assuming it not a convention in languages other than Python) since that part of the prettifier looks to be largely language-agnostic.

Comment: Yes, Prettify is quite primitive really.